# Invalid port used by Browser Link in .NET Core application

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have my app configured to use Kestrel and port 54321 for local debugging.
Previously, when the project was started I used port 12345.
Browser Link Dashboard shows always 0 connections despite I connect browsers (I tried Edge, IE, Firefox, Chrome and Visual Studio internal browser)
. Debugging works, browsing works, Browser Link Dashboard shows zero connections.

When I click "View in Browser" link, it opens the address http://localhost:12345/ which is NOT CONFIGURED ANYWHERE! The string doesn't exist in entire solution. At least in cannot be found using Shift+Ctrl+F.

> Find all "localhost:12345", Subfolders, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, "*.*"
>     Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 825

I think Browser Link doesn't work because it expects the connections be made to port 12345 instead of 54321. I have no idea where this stupid port address is stored and how to change it. I have explicitly configured "App URL" configurations. Both "Browse with" and "Debug" options work properly. The effective port used is 54321.

BTW, I can't use port 12345 because it's used on my PC by GOG Galaxy service.

I tested it both with Kestrel and IIS configurations. Browsing works, Browser Link doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I haven't found the answer about wrong port number, I found the answer why the Browser Link feature didn't work. It is not obvious at all.

To make Browser Link feature work I had to uninstall `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader` NuGet package and install `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink`.

Those packages have exactly the same description! Anyway, it works.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I saw in Firefox' Web Developer Console, that the port used by the BrowserLink javascript was not correct. Clicking on the error message brought up a warning to accept the certificate for localhost, and after accepting the certificate, BrowserLink worked again. I realized that the error was with the browser after discovering that BrowserLink worked with other browser and that just Firefox was broken and showed a wrong port number.

Comment: Can't click on error message

Comment: Did you check if using a different browser works? 
Btw. I find it unfair to downvote the answer. Your problem might be solved differently than described above, but that does not mean my answer is inorrect. Personally, I downvote only answers that are incorrect, not answers that don't solve my problem, that's a difference.

Comment: I checked with Chrome and Firefox. Maybe you're right about the downvote, but SO won't let me undo my vote, unless you edit your answer